# Matrix tag not working after 2.8.1 upg

Tags: matrix

Before 2.8.1 upg i had `{if my_matrix_field:total_rows >= 2}` but now i have to remove these so my page loads.

All EE and add-ons are current

thanks

Milke2

Comment: Hi Milke, this is a Q&A forum so you need to try and ask a question rather than make a statement. If it's a bug report then you're always better off going straight to the developers who will confirm if it is a bug and can issue an appropriate patch.

Comment: I've just given this a test with EE 2.8.1 and Matrix 2.5.10 and it seems to work as expected for me. Can you look to update your question to include your template code where the Matrix is involved along with confirming the version of Matrix you're currently using?